# Sbt external process can't process `eval` command

Tags: bash, scala, sbt, eval

Running in `sbt` command `"eval $(minikube docker-env)" !! log` give exception.

```
[error] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "eval": error=2, No such file or directory
```

but same command in bash script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Runn as `"eval.sh" !! log`
Work fine.
I can't understand why. Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`eval` is a shell feature. There is no way to call it from java to set up the environment for future commands the way you can for a shell.

If you want to run a second command from Java that depends on doing `eval "$(minikube docker-env)"` first, you can instead run a single shell with both commands:

```
String shellCommand = "eval \"$(minikube docker-env)\"; your-second-command";
Runtime.exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c", shellCommand });
```